# unable to uniquely locate the user-role dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

how to locate the user-role dropdown uniquely ? the attribute and values of the user-role dropdown are same as that of status. how to identify the user-role uniquely using css or xpath ?

html code for both the dropdown is highlighted

[image: 1]

I tried all combinations of xpath and css. still unable to locate it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve your end goal:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

url = 'https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/'
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="username"]'))).send_keys('Admin')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="password"]'))).send_keys('admin123')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Admin"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="oxd-button oxd-button--medium oxd-button--secondary"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="oxd-select-wrapper"]')))[0].click()
## let's look at the dropdown with options structure
print(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@role="listbox"]'))).get_attribute('outerHTML'))
## do you want to make it an Admin?
# wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@role="listbox"]//span[text()="Admin"]'))).click()
## do you want to make it an ESS?
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@role="listbox"]//span[text()="ESS"]'))).click()
## moving on to the next dropdown
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="oxd-select-wrapper"]')))[1].click()
### please continue yourself
```

You can find Selenium documentation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).